# How to do method((List<Integer>)null) in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, casting

I have these two methods in Java and I wrote a test for them in Kotlin.

```
public List<Team> getTeams(List<Integer> ids) ...

public List<Team> getTeams(User user) ...
```

In my test in Kotlin I want to test the first method with argument `null`.

```
assertThat(userRepository.getTeams(null)).isEmpty()
```

But this does not compile because the call is ambiguous. In Java I can do the following to fix the ambiguity.

```
assertThat(userRepository.getTeams((List<Team>)null)).isEmpty();
```

How can I achieve that in Kotlin?

Comment: `as List<Team>` doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call those methods with null arguments like this:

```
userRepository.getTeams(null as List<Int>?)
userRepository.getTeams(null as User?)
```